# Why are private methods in Java implicitly final?

Tags: java, overriding, private, final

I wanted to point this lines in the book "Java in a Nutshell" which caused me some confusion:

> private methods are not inherited by subclasses and, therefore, cannot be overridden (i.e., all private methods are implicitly final).

I interpreted that all private methods are final, and I understand that:

- Final methods cannot be overriden, but they can be called from a subclass.
- Private methods cannot be overriden, and they cannot be called from a subclass.

Are my statements correct?

Comment: final methods cannot be overridden. That's all final does. They can or can't be called by subclasses depending on their visibility modifier (public, private, protected or none). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: The text is saying that `private` methods are `final`, not otherwise. So, *Final methods cannot be overriden, but they can be called from a subclass* is a misunderstanding. The second statement is correct.

Comment: You're right. I didn't think in visibility at that time.

Comment: If I recall it correctly, the book also talks about final method optimizations. I think that the reason why they brought `final` into this context is to show that the same optimizations apply to private methods as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Final methods cannot be overriden, but they can be called from a subclass.

This may or may not be true, depending on the modifier, and where your overriding class is. If the method is private or default (no modifier) then you cannot call the method from a subclass, unless your subclass is in the same package.

> Private methods cannot be overriden, and they cannot be called from a subclass.

True. The reason private methods cannot be overridden, is because they can't be seen. This does not imply that methods that cannot be overridden are private however.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it will help if you think about this keywords in succesion.

> private

this is access modifier, it states which class can see this method. (i.e only this class, subclass, other class in a package). Hence any method that is labelled private can only be seen from within the same class. Therefore your statement is correct, as method labeled private cannot be seen from any subclass, let alone overridden or called.

> final

this states that anything withing the { } of this method can't be changed from outside. Hence any method that is labelled final can't be overridden. However method labelled final can be called from other classes depending on its access modifier. Therefore your statement about final is also correct, but again the call part depends strictly on access modifier of a method.

Answer (score 0):

> `final` cant override
>
> `private` can't use in outside class such as subclass.

**`private` methods are implicitly final** so you can't override.

**`final` method not always private** so you can access in subclass if this is not private.